# HTML-Structure dilema - use POST or GET or XHR action to delete an item by data from the database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page where it shows content inside a table, and let's you delete a row if you click on it.

Now my rows are structured like this:

```
        foreach ($rewards as $reward) {
            echo '<tr id="' . $reward['item_id'] . '" title="Delete ' . $reward['item_name'] . '">';
            echo '<td>' . $reward['item_id'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $reward['item_name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $reward['item_amount'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td><img src="'. $reward['item_image_url'] .'"/></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
```

Now the problem is, I always thought that `POST` requests are used to to post an action (Modify database as-well) with data and get the response, where `GET` requests are used to fetch data using the sent data and get the response.

Now I got told that I should be using GET requests for it, but some people say I should not use GET requests for delete actions, because of many reasons, but the main reason was *"Because you can accidentally execute it through a simple web request"*

My problem to use POST is, I would need to either create new form for every row *which is a bit  messy in my opinion* or use one form, and submit button in each row, and set the submit button value as the item id I want to delete, or just set whole row as an input which is also messy.

Probably the best solution you can think of will be using XHR requests which requires javascript, but I really want my site to function both for javascript disablers.

Friend of my quoted:

*"i think you should cover the case that they dont have javascript
quite a few workplaces disable javascript for some reason"*

**My question is, what would be more suitable for this? a GET request, POST or DELETE with XHR?**

*What I am trying to do by the way, is deleting an item from the database by id, so in GET requests the id would be `/admin/rewards/delete/14444`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one sentence: Use XHR or an AJAX POST request - choose whichever implementation - if JavaScript is enabled, but fall back to a simple POST when it is disabled.

You really do *not* want to use GET for a few reasons. By the book, GET requests should be a repeatable action that does not alter the state of any objects. This really is for a reason. They can be "accidentally executed through a simple web request" as you point out. This means a user, malicious or simply by mistake, can just type in an address and poof, you've deleted something. But the true danger here is exacerbated by search engines, some of which religiously follow every link. *Side effects of GET requests should be avoided at all costs.*

Additionally, I'm one of the (potentially increasing number of) users who fly with scripting off by default. As a matter of principle I find sites that require JavaScript for any basic functionality a detractor. I'm all for using script to make a site look or feel pretty, or for advanced features, but I still believe you should support those of us who choose to disable scripting. As you mention, there may also be workplaces which disable JavaScript, so the user doesn't even have a choice. Therefore I personally recommend falling back to a form for each row with a Delete button. (I don't think it's *that* ugly to code in a form for each row - maybe two or three tags to add in your loop?)

Comment: Maybe you're right, form for every row isn't that big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I would use both Ajax and POST requests, the implementation being the same in the backend, the only different thing being what the php code returns.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/rewards/delete/">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value=1444" />
  <input type="submit" value="Delete item" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(
       '/admin/rewards/delete/?type=ajax',
       $(this).serialize(),
       function(data){
           console.log(data.variable);
       },
       'json'
    );
});
```

PHP:

```
// DELETE item by using $_POST['id'];

// return the result depending on the method used:

if (isset($_GET['type'] && $_GET['type'] == 'ajax') {
    echo json_encode(array('variable' => 'value'));
} else {
    // this is just an example of what you can do if there wasn't an ajax request
    header('Location: success.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other two answers, why not make a big form surrounding the whole table, a submit button in each row with a value of the ID to be deleted? In your php you can then figure out the ID and process the request.